# How to use Azure Cognitive Search for Text Extraction after Applying OCR etc. Can I Perform Chunking and Embedding Creation on this Extracted Text?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, langchain, azure-openai, llama-index

I am currently working on a project where I need to leverage Azure Cognitive Search to extract text data from diverse file formats such as PDFs, Docs, Images, and CSVs. The goal is to utilize various capabilities within Azure Cognitive Search, including OCR (Optical Character Recognition) and language translation functionalities.

we are already using ACS for full text search, so if we could take out the text extracted from ACS ,do the embeddings over it and use it for hybrid search, that will be great.

My primary concern revolves around the subsequent processing steps after text extraction. Specifically, I need to understand if it's possible to obtain the extracted text from Azure Cognitive Search in a way that allows for further operations such as chunking and embedding creation.

Text Extraction:

Successfully integrating Azure Cognitive Search for extracting text data from different file formats.
OCR and Language Translation:

Confirming the implementation of OCR and language translation capabilities within Azure Cognitive Search for extracting meaningful information from images and translating text.

Chunking Operation:

Exploring the feasibility of performing chunking operations on the extracted text. This involves breaking down the text into smaller, manageable segments or chunks as the search results are huge and needs to be chunked to reduce the token expenses.

Embedding Creation:

Understanding if it's possible to access the extracted text [not the search results, but teh text over which the indexing is done] from Azure Cognitive Search to create embeddings. These embeddings are required for implementing hybrid search.

Any guidance, best practices, or examples related to this specific scenario within the Azure Cognitive Search ecosystem would be greatly appreciated.

I am currently using Full text search, but the search results are too huge and needs to be chunked. i cannot chunk the result after querying as it may take a lot of time. if there are any approaches that is not very compute intensive, please mention the same.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you check out our new preview [Integrated Vectorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/vector-search-integrated-vectorization) feature. This feature is designed to allow you to automatically extract text from your documents, chunk it into manageable sizes, and generate embeddings while you index your content from any Azure data source. There is a really easy to use portal wizard to help get you started, described in [this blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-azure-ai-services-blog/announcing-the-public-preview-of-integrated-vectorization-in/ba-p/3960809).

In addition, you can easily accomplish your additional requirements for adding OCR and text translation by adding on additional skills to your skillset. There is a built in skill for both of those needs. That customization won't be available from the portal wizard experience, but here is [a demo notebook](https://github.com/Azure/azure-search-vector-samples/blob/main/demo-python/code/azure-search-integrated-vectorization-sample.ipynb) where you could make those edits yourself.